# Inputting three integers in a line separated by spaces

Tags: c++, input, space

I'm fairly new to programming using C++.

How can I get an output like this?

```
Input three numbers:
1 2 3
```

Where 1, 2, and 3 are declared as integers.

Comment: What is your question and where is your code?

Comment: I am not clear on your question. We have many way to print out for your output. Pls show us your codes.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "Input three numbers:" << std::endl;

int value1, value2,  value3;

if (std::cin >> value1 >> value2 >> value3)
{
    // use values as needed...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how you will get something like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGjml.jpg

The code for which is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Input three numbers:\n" ;
    int i1 =0 , i2 = 0, i3 = 0 ;
    cin >> i1 >> i2 >> i3 ;
}
```